# How UIToolbarPosition is handled by UIToolbar?

Tags: uikit, uitoolbar, uitoolbarposition

I'm using setBackgroundImage:forToolbarPosition:metrics: method of UIToolbar.
That's my code:

```
toolbar = [[UIToolbar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,0, 320, 44)];
[toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"top"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionTop barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[toolbar setBackgroundImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom"] forToolbarPosition:UIToolbarPositionBottom barMetrics:UIBarMetricsDefault];
[self.view addSubview:toolbar];
```

As you can see I've put my toolbar on top. However when I run the code the toolbar image used is [UIImage imageNamed:@"bottom"].

How UIToolbarPosition is obtained?
My first idea is frame check ( < 1/2 superview frame is top, otherwise is bottom... or sort of).

It still on bottom. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

on iPhone UIToolbarPosition is always on bottom because UIToolbar is not supposed to be on top.

on iPad it works fine, UIToolbarPositionTop is used when toolbar.frame.origin.y = 0, UIToolbarPositionBottom otherwise.